# How can I pass a dependency to a constructor function which is needed by its prototype/base class

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, requirejs

I have a chicken or egg who was first there... problem.

The AlarmOverlay derives from OverlayView.

Before the AlarmOverlay is created by calling the constructor function the 'google' object is already needed for the inheritation from OverlayView. But the google object is just passed with the constructor...

I can not inject the google object with requirejs because I write a unit test with this AlarmOverlay class so any http calls must be avoided... I am passing in my own google fake object.

How do I have to rewrite my code, that the google object is not undefined when the new google.maps.OverlayView() call is done?

```
    define(['jquery','inject google here is not allowed because of the unit test'], function($) {

    AlarmOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    function AlarmOverlay(bounds, alarmNumber, alarmCssClass , google) {

        this.google = google;
    }    

    AlarmOverlay.prototype.createMapOnOverlay = function (map) {

    };

    AlarmOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    };

    AlarmOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

    };

    return AlarmOverlay;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure requirejs to pass in a **[mock google object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)** when unit testing, and pass in the real google object when running in production. That way, your AlarmOverlay object will not need to change in either scenario.

A mock object simulates the behavior of an object so that your unit can call the mock without surprises. In this case, your mock object will need to implement `maps.OverlayView,` perhaps like this:

**mygoogle.js**

```
define(function() {
   return {
    maps: { OverlayView: function() {} }
  }
}
```

Then, during testing, you map the `google` module to `mymodule`, perhaps like so:

**main.js or page.html**

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
      google: '../mocks/mygoogle.js'
  }
});
```

During production you map the google module to the full-fledged google object:

**main.js or page.html**

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
      google: '[your production google]'
  }
});
```

Now you can use the same code for production and testing:

**alarmOverlay.js**

```
define(['jquery','google'], function($, google) {

/* reference 'google' anywhere in this module */ 
function AlarmOverlay(bounds, alarmNumber, alarmCssClass) {

}    

AlarmOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

AlarmOverlay.prototype.createMapOnOverlay = function (map) {

};

AlarmOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

};

AlarmOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

};

return AlarmOverlay;

});
```